# hbase createtable failed from windows

Tags: java, hbase

I setup hbase 0.98.13 on ubuntu and it looks working ok. I have a Java client sample program in Windows to create a table in hbase. If I package the java program and ftp to the ubuntu and run the java client locally, it can create the hbase table 'people'. However if I run the java program from Windows, the hbase table is not created. The hbase log shows a session is established from my windows PC, which is 10.154.14.43. But nothing happened after that. here is the hbase log when I run the java client from windows.

```
2015-09-02 11:05:14,477 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /10.154.14.43:59780
2015-09-02 11:05:14,479 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.ZooKeeperServer: Client attempting to establish new session at /10.154.14.43:59780
2015-09-02 11:05:14,500 INFO  [SyncThread:0] server.ZooKeeperServer: Established session 0x14f8bf64aa20026 with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /10.154.14.43:59780
2015-09-02 11:05:19,013 DEBUG [LruStats #0] hfile.LruBlockCache: Total=415.43 KB, free=386.27 MB, max=386.68 MB, blockCount=4, accesses=99, hits=95, hitRatio=95.96%, , cachingAccesses=99, cachingHits=95, cachingHitsRatio=95.96%, evictions=89, evicted=0, evictedPerRun=0.0
2015-09-02 11:05:25,149 DEBUG [cju-linux,33912,1441162218543-BalancerChore] balancer.BaseLoadBalancer: Not running balancer because only 1 active regionserver(s)
2015-09-02 11:10:19,013 DEBUG [LruStats #0] hfile.LruBlockCache: Total=415.43 KB, free=386.27 MB, max=386.68 MB, blockCount=4, accesses=101, hits=97, hitRatio=96.04%, , cachingAccesses=101, cachingHits=97, cachingHitsRatio=96.04%, evictions=119, evicted=0, evictedPerRun=0.0
2015-09-02 11:10:25,149 DEBUG [cju-linux,33912,1441162218543-BalancerChore] balancer.BaseLoadBalancer: Not running balancer because only 1 active regionserver(s)
2015-09-02 11:15:19,013 DEBUG [LruStats #0] hfile.LruBlockCache: Total=415.43 KB, free=386.27 MB, max=386.68 MB, blockCount=4, accesses=103, hits=99, hitRatio=96.12%, , cachingAccesses=103, cachingHits=99, cachingHitsRatio=96.12%, evictions=149, evicted=0, evictedPerRun=0.0
2015-09-02 11:15:25,150 DEBUG [cju-linux,33912,1441162218543-BalancerChore] balancer.BaseLoadBalancer: Not running balancer because only 1 active regionserver(s)
2015-09-02 11:18:01,831 WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxn: Exception causing close of session 0x14f8bf64aa20026 due to java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
2015-09-02 11:18:01,832 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /10.154.14.43:59780 which had sessionid 0x14f8bf64aa20026
2015-09-02 11:18:42,000 INFO  [SessionTracker] server.ZooKeeperServer: Expiring session 0x14f8bf64aa20026, timeout of 40000ms exceeded
2015-09-02 11:18:42,000 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x14f8bf64aa20026
```

Here is the log when I run the java client from the same ubuntu.

```
2015-09-02 10:54:22,890 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:49964
2015-09-02 10:54:22,892 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.ZooKeeperServer: Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:49964
2015-09-02 10:54:22,909 INFO  [SyncThread:0] server.ZooKeeperServer: Established session 0x14f8bf64aa2001b with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /127.0.0.1:49964
2015-09-02 10:54:23,267 INFO  [FifoRpcScheduler.handler1-thread-14] master.HMaster: Client=hduser/null create 'people', {NAME => 'contactinfo', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'false', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 'name', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'false', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
2015-09-02 10:54:23,269 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x14f8bf64aa20000 type:create cxid:0x206 zxid:0x21d txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/table-lock/people Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/table-lock/people
2015-09-02 10:54:23,342 DEBUG [FifoRpcScheduler.handler1-thread-14] lock.ZKInterProcessLockBase: Acquired a lock for /hbase/table-lock/people/write-master:339120000000000
2015-09-02 10:54:23,370 INFO  [MASTER_TABLE_OPERATIONS-cju-linux:33912-0] handler.CreateTableHandler: Create table people
2015-09-02 10:54:23,382 DEBUG [MASTER_TABLE_OPERATIONS-cju-linux:33912-0] util.FSTableDescriptors: Wrote descriptor into: file:/home/hduser/hbase/.tmp/data/default/people/.tabledesc/.tableinfo.0000000001
```

As you see, the following line shows up when I run the java client from ubuntu.

```
[FifoRpcScheduler.handler1-thread-14] master.HMaster: Client=hduser/null create 'people', .....
```

And here is my source code.

```
public class CreateTable {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

    // Example of setting zookeeper values for HDInsight
    //   in code instead of an hbase-site.xml file
    //
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "cju-linux");
    //config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
    //config.set("hbase.cluster.distributed", "true");

    System.out.println("before creating table people 1111111111");
    // create an admin object using the config
    HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(config);

    System.out.println("before creating table people 22222222");
    // create the table...
    HTableDescriptor tableDescriptor = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf("people"));
    // ... with two column families
    tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("name"));
    tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("contactinfo"));
    System.out.println("before creating table people 33333");
    admin.createTable(tableDescriptor);
    System.out.println("before creating table people 4444");

    // define some people
    String[][] people = {
        { "1", "Marcel", "Haddad", "marcel@fabrikam.com"},
        { "2", "Franklin", "Holtz", "franklin@contoso.com" },
        { "3", "Dwayne", "McKee", "dwayne@fabrikam.com" },
        { "4", "Rae", "Schroeder", "rae@contoso.com" },
        { "5", "Rosalie", "burton", "rosalie@fabrikam.com"},
        { "6", "Gabriela", "Ingram", "gabriela@contoso.com"} };

    System.out.println("before creating table people xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    HTable table = new HTable(config, "people1");

    System.out.println("After creating table people");
    // Add each person to the table
    //   Use the `name` column family for the name
    //   Use the `contactinfo` column family for the email
    for (int i = 0; i< people.length; i++) {
      Put person = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(people[i][0]));
      person.add(Bytes.toBytes("name"), Bytes.toBytes("first"), Bytes.toBytes(people[i][1]));
      person.add(Bytes.toBytes("name"), Bytes.toBytes("last"), Bytes.toBytes(people[i][2]));
      person.add(Bytes.toBytes("contactinfo"), Bytes.toBytes("email"), Bytes.toBytes(people[i][3]));
      table.put(person);
    }
    // flush commits and close the table
    table.flushCommits();
    table.close();
  }
```

When I run the java client from windows, the message "before creating table people 33333" is printed out, but the message "before creating table people 4444" is not printed out.

After turning on debug, the java client program running on windows prints out this message

```
2015-09-02 15:41:25,737 INFO  [main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 2 of 35 failed; retrying after sleep of 200, exception=com.google.protobuf.ServiceException:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: localhost/127.0.0.1:48285
```

I have googled and changed my /etc/hosts file on ubuntu to like this

```
10.154.14.5 localhost cju-linux
```

I restarted hbase, it still does not work.

How do I debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when you run it on windows it is having trouble connecting to the cluster or speaking the correct protocol.  Make sure your windows machine is able to connect to all the machines in the cluster (check the zookeeper, hmaster, and region server hosts and ports).  If it can connect alright, verify that the client and server are both using a compatible version (i.e. 0.98.x).  You can also try stepping through the createTable command.  If you let it run for a long long time you will likely also see an exception when it gives up retries that may give you more clues.  You could reduce the client retries to try to make that happen sooner.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the Zookeeper data directory. In order to do it, stop the Zookeeper, check in your hbase-site.xml the value of the hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir property, clear this directory and restart the Zookeeper.